# How to fix 'cannot call a method on a null-valued expression' in Powershell with Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

We created a Power Shell script to read parts of an excel file as save the require range as an image.  When run from the ISE (64 or x86), it runs fine - the images generated are exactly what we expect.   When we try to run this as part of a CMD file - it fails.  We have tried both the version of powershell in c:\windows\system32 and the version in c:\windows\sysWOW64.  The code fails on the .save method below:

The full text of the error message (task scheduler or from the cmd prompt)

*You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
at c:\scripts\dumpexcel.ps1:41 char:31
 +$oIMG.save <<<< ($sFNM, $vFMT)
 + CategoryInfo : Invalid Operation: (save:String) [], RuntimeException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorID: InvokeMethodOnNull*

```
 if ($oWKS.cells.item($erow,"C").value2 -match "Total") {
     $oWKS.range("a" + $iTOT + ":K" + $erow).copy() 
     $vFMT = [system.drawing.imaging.imageformat]::Jpeg
     $oIMG=[windows.forms.clipboard]::GetImage();
     $sFNM="c:\temp\"+$sFNM+"."+$vFMT

     $oIMG.save($sFNM, $vFMT)
}
```

Comment: Can you please include more of the error message? I think the error is from if you are running it in Task Scheduler, you run it as a new session, and so, you won't be able to get an image from the clipboard.

Comment: Original post updated with complete error message

Comment: Yeah from the error message, it definitely looks like the `$oIMG` is not getting set because there is nothing on the clipboard. The only thing I think of to try is to try running the Task Scheduler "Run only when the user is logged on" and run as yourself.

Comment: Ok - we did do that - even from a command prompt we get the error.  This is odd.

Comment: it looks like you are working with excel via a COM object. are you _certain_ that the excel COM object is available to the account that is running that code? my understanding is that excel MUST be run at least once by an account to make the COM stuff available for that account.

Comment: Yes - we are running the script from the batch file with the same account that can run it from the ISE.  We have also displayed the worksheet names, the data that is in the cells, etc at this point in time.  It seems to be an issue with using the clipboard.